# Domain updating in grails 3.2.9

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm, grails3, grails3.2.0

I have a problem after upgrading from grails 2.3.11 to version 3.2.9.
We have changed what was needed and almost everything works great. But we still have only one problem.

Some action in app have this pattern:

1. On click in UI there is ajax request which which updates/inserts data into DB.
2. After success there is callback with another ajax which retrieves updated/new data.

Sometimes (very rarely), second ajax gets old data(of course after another request, data is updated). Database did not have enough time to save the data ? ;)

In grails 2 this never happened. 
We use postgres 8.4, but after update to 9.6, problem still occurs. Changing jdbc driver didn't help too.

To reproduce this, I have created a simple app. I added some records to the DB and created 2 actions. One action adds a domain and returns a new id, the second gets data after the insert (there is only one assert which checks if a domain with the right id was created in the DB). 
When I have postgres DB on a local, fast machine, the problem occurred very, very rarely, but on the local network, a slow machine causes the problem to appear more frequently.
The problem did not occurr with the default H2 database.

https://github.com/kuchar90/grails3.2Test

Is this normal behavior? Do you have an idea where to look for the reason for this issue?

Comment: I'm no expert at this kind of things, but I would try those :
-remove JDBC batch
-add Transactional to the second method
-change the config to read 'uncommitted' data
This could give you more information to understand what is happening.